# SVG objects in HTML pointer events

Tags: html, svg, object-tag

If layering some SVGs via `object` tags, the topmost one always consume all mouse events it seems.

This contradicts the `pointer-events: auto` default value of SVGs.

I tried a heap of workarounds by settings `pointer-events` for the `object` elements and elements inside it's `contentDocument` SVG DOM, but it just behaves like `object` is just an rectangular area, despite the mostly transparent SVG content. Only applying `pointer-events: none` to the `object` has an effect, and it disables any interaction with the SVG content.

Why is that and what could be done about?

Merging the SVGs into a single `svg` tag is not an option, as they use overlapping namespaces.

Comment: SVGs do include nodes using unique ids, if you add mutliple SVGs to a single HTML DOM, the ids are not neccessary unique, and the SVGs may be broken. Eg. the SVG `use` tags `xref` attribute links other nodes by id, which won't work anymore then. So adding multiple SVGs into a single HTML DOM may change the SVG content.

Comment: Fix the SVGs to have unique IDs then.

Comment: Well, the SVGs aren't broken. It's totally ok for two SVGs to use the same id on some element. 'Fixing' them would mean to find all allowed references to a certain id inside the SVG DOM (attributes, CSS, JS), which is not that easy for the full SVG standard as whole.

Comment: All elements in the same document (whether they be SVG, HTML, MATHML and anything else) must be unique. If you have 2 identical ids they need to be in 2 different documents.

Comment: Thats why merging them is not an option, as stated in the question.